# How do I change the function field in excel to show Bengali Characters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, language, translation

I received an excel file that has columns translated from english to Bengali. I have a Bengali font installed and it shows up in the main body of the spreadsheet but the characters are not showing up in the function field when I click on individual cells. Instead it is showing random letters and symbols. Same thing happens if I copy/paste.

How can I fix this so that the Bengali characters show up in the function field?

Comment: function field is formula bar, right? Also, how you get the tranlation done, inside excel or tranlated online and copy result to excel? Can you type in Bengali inside excel?

Comment: @ZAT the translation was done by someone in Bangladesh. I have a Bengali font installed so when I type it looks like Bengali characters but I'm sure it would mean nothing if translated.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116963/bengali-language-text-not-displayed-in-unicode-csv-file). what bengali font are you using?

Comment: Have you set up your language preferences for Office? Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Office 2010 -> Microsoft Office 2010 Tools -> Microsoft Office 2010 Language Preferences.